# Editing filenames by searching for a char

Tags: bash, unix

So I have problem for an assignment which requires me to search for all .mp3 files in a directory that have a naming convention similar to:

```
Beatles - Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds.mp3
```

Then, I need to put that in a format similar to:

```
Beatles/Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds.mp3
```

I am pretty new to UNIX but I have a good grasp of basic concepts.

I know how to "strip" the extension off of the filename (so "Beatles - Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds" would be left).

I also know how to search for all the files in the directory.

However, I am unfamiliar with how to search for the "-".

I know in C++ and the like I can search for a particular char ("-") and get that int and create substrings but I don't know of any such function in UNIX.

I am not looking for complete code to completely answer the question, but I would like to know how to go about searching for the char and editing the filename.

Thanks.

EDITS:

Using what nosid said, I managed to get the filename to split between artist and song title like this:

```
artist="${originalFile%% - *}"
song="${originalFile#* - }"
```

So that part works and separates them property but a new issue arises when I try to move the files. I have 2 if statements that detect if the directory exists, and if it does not, it will create that directory. However, if I use the artist variable for the directory name, it will create 2 directories. The same goes for using the song.

So essentially, how can I have it so that the spaces are ignored in the file/dir name when I try mkdir or mv similar to this:

```
mkdir ${artist};
mv ${artist}/${song};
```

Comment: Google "bash tr", "bash grep", "bash awk", "bash for loops" and you will find tons of information on how to do this.

Comment: You have to use quotes around the variables, i.e. `"$artist"` instead of `${artist}`. Please do not edit questions to ask for other things. Ask a new question and search for similar questions first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *parameter expansion* with `%%` and `#` to remove everything the longest matching suffix and the shortest matching prefix:

```
source="Beatles - Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds.mp3"
target="${source%% - *}/${source#* - }"
```

You can also use *pattern substitution*:

```
source="Beatles - Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds.mp3"
target="${source/ - //}"
```

Comment: First off, thank you for the timely response and help.

I updated my question as I ran into a slight problem with the method you provided. Can you help me on this problem as well?

Answer (score 1):

To identify the files, loop over a wildcard match.

```
for file in *\ -\ *.mp3; do
    artist="${file%% - *}"
    song="${file#* -  }"
    :
done
```

The body of the loop is essentially the same as @nosid's answer. You may need to fiddle with the whitespace in the parameter substitution, depending on your shell. (Maybe backslash the spaces for old versions of Bash, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `awk` program:

```
$echo "Beatles - Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds.mp3" |
awk -F- '{
  gsub(/ *$/, "", $1);
  gsub(/^ */, "", $2);
  print $1 "/" $2}'
```

This outputs

```
Beatles/Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds.mp3
```

The `-F-` option splits fields on the "-" character, so `$1` is "Beatles " (with trailing space), and `$2` is " Lucy in the Sky with Diamonds.mp3" (with leading space). The two `gsub` commands remove these spaces and `print` prints them with a "/" in between.